# Версия 2.1.63 сломался параметр json метода geocode

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Вместо JSON возвращает геообъекты.

```
ymaps.geocode(req, {
    boundedBy: map.getBounds(),
    results: 1,
    json: true
}).then(function (res){
    var jsonResult = JSON.stringify(res);
    OnGeocode(jsonResult);
   }, function (err){
       OnGeocode(err);
      });
```

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, в вопрос пример ответа, который вы получаете от geocode

Comment: анализ показал что данные передаются в function (err)
и если там добавить JSON.stringify(err);
возвращает

GeoObjectCollection : metaDataProperty : GeocoderResponseMetaData : request : 45.045296551,41.970320477
results : 1
skip : 0
boundedBy : 0 : 0 : 41.96631665
1 : 45.04218351

1 : 0 : 41.97452725
1 : 45.04800423


found : 9
Point : type : Point
coordinates : 0 : 41.97042195
1 : 45.04509394

и т.д.

Comment: а что не так? в 2.1.63 не было изменений геокодера, вроде как всё работает и JSON на месте: https://jsfiddle.net/7h1cqq1c/1/